# "Clogit" created unintended and NA factor, and deleted original factor

Tags: r

I'm using `clogit` for conditional logistic regression.
However, in the result table, `factor1` disappeared and instead, `factor1_1` was automatically created.

I never made this `factor1_1` in original data
Moreover, the result of `clogit` for `factor1_1` is all `NA`.

So, I could not know the coef, se and Z value for `factor1`.
For other variables such as `factor2~5`, I could get the result.

Firstly, I changed type of `factor1`.
It was `factor` first and I converted into `numeric` or `integer`, but the result was same.

`Factor1` is the data of sex which was coded in `0` r `1`, and there was no missing data.

```
clogit(outcome ~ factor1 + factor2 + factor3 + factor4 + factor5 + factor6 + 
       strata(matchid),
       method = "exact",
       data = df)
```

There was no error message.
Just the result of `clogit` for `factor1` is `NA`.

Comment: Could you provide some more information on what the data looks like? For instance a dput() of your data. Also, can you show us the format of your `factor1` column vs the others?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
Sorry, the data is confidential, so I cannot open that.

All factors are factor or numeric.
Factor1 is categorical variable recorded as 0 or 1 which means male or female.

Comment: Data frame include a number of persons in columns and several variables (like sex, age, barth place) in row.

Comment: I tried the same analysis with "glm".
I could get the result parameter for factor1, but again, the name of factor1 was automatically changed to factor1_1.